# How do I debug React Native native module in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, debugging

Looking for an answer I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38007808 
However I don't know how to...

> launch the React Native packager beforehand

as Jean Regisser suggest to do before in order to start debugging.

This is what I tried so far:

1. Go to android studio and press play button
2. Run react-native start and press play button from android studio
3. Run gradlew clean --> react-native start --> press play

Nothing works. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way:

1. Start process like normal
2. In android studio, press the button to attach debugger to a running app.

And that's it!

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#attach-debugger to know which button I meant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should open the android bin(which you have in your react native project) with android studio. And run "npm start" in your project.

**And follow these instructions:**  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html